# Design Pattern for varied input to create collection of objects

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Let's say I have the following simple class

```
<?php
class Variable
{
    private $variableName;
    private $variableValue;

    public function __construct($name, $value)
    {
        $this->variableName  = $name;
        $this->variableValue = $value;
    }
}
```

I am keeping the  `Variable` objects in a collection of the following `Collection` class.

```
class Collection
{ 
    private $items = array();

    public function addItem($obj) {
        // Code for adding an item
    }

    // Other methods delete, sort, filter, etc

}
```

Also, let's say I'm using a very inconsistent API to import a bunch of variable names and values. The API returns JSON but it could really be anything.

I say the API is inconsistent because depending upon your URI, the Variable object could return `$raw` data in this format:

```
{  
    "variables" : [  
        {  
            "name" : "variable_one",
            "value" : "foo"
        },
        {
            "name" : "variable_two",
            "value" : "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or the `$raw` data could be in this format:

```
{  
   "dataObject" : {  
      "variable_one" : "foo",
      "variable_two" : "bar"
   }
}
```

In addition, this API is still maturing and I can foresee them making unpredictable changes to the `$raw` format of the variable data in the future.

Here is my current solution for consuming the `$raw` data to get a collection of `Variable` objects:

```
<?php
    // Turn JSON into stdObject
    $variableData = json_decode($raw);

    // Collection object to hold the variables
    $variables = new Collection()


    if ( property_exists($variableData, 'variables') ) {
        foreach ( $variableData as $variable ) {

            // Use for the first type of JSON
            $variables->addItem(
                new Variable($variable->name, $variable->value)
            );

        }
    } else {
        foreach ($variableData as $key => $value) {

            // Use for the second type of JSON
            $variables->addItem(new Variable($key, $value);

        }
    }
```

The problem with this solution is that if the variable constructor becomes more complex, or the number of different formats `$raw` can be grows, this solution becomes a big fat mess.

If the `Variable` grows in complexity and requires a `VariableFactory`, I would need to create a separate factory for each type of `$raw` input. If the number of types of `$raw` input grows, the above code becomes a big fat mess of `if` and `elseif` statements.

Is there's a good design pattern I can use for varied `$raw` input to create a `Collection` of `Variable` objects?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the mess of if statements you could use the Visitor pattern. Essentially each branch of the if statement gets wrapped in a function. Each function takes two arguments: an “instruction” and an object. If the function “recognizes” the instruction, it does something to the object. Otherwise it silently returns.

You can can create an array of these “visitor” functions and loop over them for each element in your input data.

This is a simplified explanation (I’m typing on a phone) but hopefully it points you in the right direction.